# Lost in the upload bandwidth in Windows Server 2016

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016, windows-update, lsass

I have problems with the performance of my network connector, the upload speed exceeds the bandwidth.

I look at the resource monitor and I realize that the Lsass.exe process with PID 844 is the cause of the exessive network activity.

I tried to change the network connector, I installed the updates but I could not find the root cause of the problem.

[image: WAN Adapter]

[image: Lsass.exe Process]

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2789917/heavy-wan-and-domain-controller-cpu-usage-when-you-perform-system-stat

Answer (score 1):

Run [tcpview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview) and check what is the remote endpoint, it will provide you knowledge of what cause it.

Edit: I seen your result from tcpview. Please know that multihoming a DC bring challenge.. As such your tcpview show that it’s your own server that talk to itself. A badly binded ADDS service to your WAN IP is the culprit. Be advised the traffic never actually hit the internet on the other side, but nonetheless it’s not ok.

As it come from lsass.exe I suspect update (and/or wsus) or upload to azure if you are linked to Azure, but in anycase the tcpview will provide you the direct answer.

Comment: Process: Lsass.exe | PID: 844 | TCP | LocalAddress: SERVIDOR | Local Port: ldap | Remote Address: SERVIDOR | Remote Port: 0 | Stated: LISTENING | Sent Packets: 44.775 | Sent Bytes: 135.589.750 | Rcvd Packets: 45.007 | Rcvd Bytes: 2.297.315

Comment: @DiegoMartinez thanks! updated my answer